# Call a function using a input string in Python

Tags: python

I have a list of strings in my program let's say it is this:

```
lst = ["ONE", "TWO", "THREE"]
```

i have the user choose one of the these via an input (which i have ensured what they have typed is in fact in lst).

Now, my actual list is longer than this, so an if statement would be copious amounts of code. i am hoping that there is a way to call a function using the name of a variable or a string that is the same as the name of a function.

so let's say i have:

```
def ONE():
     #does something
lst[0]()
```

Now, i know this definitely wouldn't work, but is there a way to do this?

Comment: My apologies, the already answered thread's title was misleading as i wanted a string to call a function whereas that thread sounds like it is referring to recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do dict

```
def One():
 #do something

funcDict = {'One':One}

funcDict[input]()
```

Comment: This works brilliantly! Thank you very much!

Comment: @AndrewO'Rourke enjoy

Answer (score 0):

Yes, like so:

```
In [5]: lst = ["ONE", "TWO", "THREE"]

In [6]: def ONE():
    print 'hello world!'
   ...:     

In [7]: locals()[lst[0]]()
hello world!
```